# Textfield in custom tableviewcell when scroll and access then crash

Tags: swift3, uitextfield, ios10, uitableview

When i add custom tableview cell which have textfield and scroll tableview
the cell disappear from screen and then i go for access value to textfield entered in that is crasing app.

Here is the code for when i go for access textfield and getting crash,

```
        let index0 : IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        let tblCell0 = tblInfo.cellForRow(at: index0)! as! MyInfromationCell
        let strEmail = tblCell0.txtEmail?.text

        let index1 : IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
        let tblCell1 = tblInfo.cellForRow(at: index1)! as! MyInfromationCell
        let strAboutMe = tblCell1.txtDescription?.text

        let index2 : IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
        let tblCell2 = tblInfo.cellForRow(at: index2)! as! MyInfromationCell
        let strStudioName = tblCell2.txtStudioName?.text

        let index3 : IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)
        let tblCell3 = tblInfo.cellForRow(at: index3)! as! MyInfromationCell
        let strWebsite = tblCell3.txtWebsite?.tex
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

When the tableview is scrolled the cell is reused, hence you get a nil when trying to access the cell which is not on the screen. Please refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifie).

You should safely unwrap the cell before accessing it.

```
let index2 : IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
guard let tblCell2 = tblInfo.cellForRow(at: index2) as? MyInfromationCell else { return }
```

This will return the function if you get a nil for the given indexpath.

Comment: But i need to get value of the textfield from it then ?
It still not working

Comment: you wont be able to fetch the value when the cell is not on screen. You can create a model object which stores the values of textfields text into a new array and you can fetch the value from that model.

Comment: Nice rameez
Thanks